# Eliminar corchetes de arreglo de objeto iterado

Tags: javascript

Tengo un objeto almacenado en una arreglo, después lo itero pero necesito almacenar el objeto en otra variable de la siguiente manera `let json : { id : 1}` pero me aparece entre corchetes necesito eliminar esos corchetes solo quiero el objeto, hay alguna manera de hacerlo?. Gracias

```
let array = [{id: 1, name: "React JS",...}]

let json = array.map(item =>{
  return { id : item.id}
})
console.log(json);

por consola obtengo : [{id : 1}]
```

Comment: ¿Solo hay un objeto? Basta con hacer referencia al primer elemento: `console.log({id: array[0].id});`

Answer (score 1):

La función [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map) te devolverá un arreglo con los valores seleccionados al terminar de iterar el arreglo asi esta en la documentación, lo que puedes si buscar un valor especifico, es, puedes usar la función filter pasando una función con el criterio a filtrar.

Answer (score 1):

Con el operador spread (simplifica la recogida de valores en una estructura de datos) eliminas los corchetes.

```js
let array = [{id: 1, name: "React JS"}];
console.log(...array);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax si te interesa saber mas

Answer (score 1):

spread operator

```
let array = [{id: 1, name: "React JS"}]

let json = array.map(item =>{
  return { id : item.id}
})
console.log(...json);
```

Answer (score 1):

Primero que todo, hay que entender las funciones, en donde `map` siempre nos va a devolver un `array` lo cual siempre tendrá corchetes al imprimir

```
//solucion 1

let array = [{id: 1, name: "React JS"}]
let json = array[0]; //las listas empiezan desde `0`
console.log(json);

//solucion 2

let array = [{id: 1, name: "React JS"}]
let [json] = array; // asignar nombre a cada posision
console.log(json);

//solucion 3
let array = [{id: 1, name: "React JS"}]
let json = array.find(item => item.id == 1); // si tienes el id y no sabes la catidad de objetos, esto es lo mas recomendable
console.log(json);
```